# Detect face different part using ARKIT

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, arkit

I read a good example of ARKit having track of

https://www.raywenderlich.com/5491-ar-face-tracking-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

- Eye (left/right) Nose  Lips

Can we detect

- Ears (left / right) head (hair) Cap  Beard  Moustache position in it?

**Also Can we track complete face with head and ear using face mask with .lines in it?**

Answer (score 3):

At this moment, there is no blend shape for **ears**, **hair**, and **cap beard**. So you can't detect/track them unless added in future ARKit releases.

You can check the complete list of supported facial expressions (blend shapes) [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfaceanchor/blendshapelocation).

Comment: any sdk with OpenCV ? as we saw such filter in tiktok and snapchat

Comment: @9to5ios it's probably possible. I searched a bit and found some projects. https://github.com/FaceAR/OpenFaceIOS it's old but worth taking a look!

Comment: Is it supported now: ears, hair, and cap beard and fingers, hands

Comment: @HariKarthick is that a question or update? I don't see they're added tho

Comment: @MReza, I just asked question. Still apple don't support ear, hand and fingers?

Comment: @HariKarthick it seems still no :(

Comment: @MReza But I see like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57323315/ears-and-neck-detection-using-arkit

Comment: @HariKarthick that's an inaccurate way with bad user experience, did you check the project I sent above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245973/discussion-between-harikarthick-and-m-reza).

Answer (score 2):

ARKit does not support ear detection.
But Firebase MLKit supports ear detection.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/face-detection-concepts

Answer (score 0):

You can just identify the corresponding vertex on the face mesh that arkit returns. The face mesh retains the same topology.