# Ears and neck detection using ARKit

Tags: arkit

I am trying to detect ears and neck to put jewelry using ARKit. Currently, I am using hardcode value to do this but this is very inaccurate for different - different face.

```
 SCNNode *contentNode = [SCNNode node];
    ARSCNFaceGeometry *faceGeometry = [ARSCNFaceGeometry   faceGeometryWithDevice:_sceneView.device];
    SCNNode *faceNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:faceGeometry];
    contentNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:faceGeometry];
    earringsPlane.firstMaterial.doubleSided = true;
    [earringsNode setPosition:SCNVector3Make(-0.09, -0.04 , -0.04)];
    earringsNode.geometry = earringsPlane;
    [earringsNode2 setPosition:SCNVector3Make(0.09, -0.04 , -0.04)];
    earringsNode2.geometry = earringsPlane2;
```

Comment: Could you please update this I need to detect ear, neck and finger same as to put jewellery.

Comment: I suggest you use google ML for face tracking: 
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection
You can find the face contour which can be used to figure out ear lobs. 
Also do check this resource : https://google.github.io/mediapipe/

Comment: Actually I started ARKit for specs and nose.